# ffmpeg prores with alpha to webm vp9 renders grey

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, vp9

I've been trying to convert a video encoded in ProRes 4444HQ to webm vp9. I created an example video with a 50% transparent square in it. It should look like this:

[image: what I want]

but it looks like this:

[image: what I get]

Here is how I'm converting the video:

ffmpeg -i square.mov -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 0 -crf 31 square.webm

I've tried changing color spaces and choosing different profiles but I can't seem to get rid of the grey shadow. Does it have something to do with the conversion from yuva to rgba?

Comment: How are you checking the input and output? Can you share the source?

Comment: I'm loading the webm into chrome and changing the background by inspecting the page. I can preview the prores version in quicklook.

Here is my testing source: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fgsk53rh7wqqkbt/original.mov?dl=0

Comment: Appears to be an issue with one of your players - possibly quicklook: with ffplay, both commands produce same output - `ffplay original.mov -vf scale=alphablend=checkerboard,format=yuv420p` and `ffplay -vcodec libvpx-vp9 -i square.webm -vf scale=alphablend=checkerboard,format=yuv420p`

Comment: One possibility is that the browser expects premultiplied pixels - test by running `ffmpeg -i square.mov -vf premultiply=inplace=1 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 0 -crf 31 square-premult.webm`

Comment: That still seems to output the same result. I've just exported a frame from Motion as PNG and here is the result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4nkuuxaumybc327/default-canvas-settings.png?dl=0 It seems to export ok so could it be something to do with the ProRes format?

Comment: Change premultiply to unpremultiply in my command.

Comment: Ahh haa. Thats done it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the ProReS has premultiplied pixels and the MOV from Motion has set a flag in the MOV indicating that but the WebM hasn't / can't, so the browser doesn't compensate.

Running

```
ffmpeg -i square.mov -vf unpremultiply=inplace=1 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 0 -crf 31 square-premult.webm
```

should produce a WebM with straight pixels handled correctly by the browser.

Comment: What is the opposite of this? From .webm to .mov?